# How to assign a subset from a data frame `a' to a subset of data frame `b'

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, variable-assignment

It might be a trivial question (I am new to R), but I could not find a answer for my question, either here in SO or anywhere else. My scenario is the following.

I have an data frame `df` and i want to update a subset `df$tag` values. `df` is similar to the following:

```
id = rep( c(1:4), 3)
tag = rep( c("aaa", "bbb", "rrr", "fff"), 3)
df = data.frame(id, tag)
```

Then, I am trying to use `match()` to update the column `tag` from the subsets of the data frame, using a second data frame (e.g., aux) that contains two columns, namely, `key` and `value`. The subsets are defined by id = n, according to `n in unique(df$id)`. `aux` looks like the following:

```
 > aux 
     key      value
   "aaa"  "valueAA"
   "bbb"  "valueBB"
   "rrr"  "valueRR"
   "fff"  "valueFF"
```

I have tried to loop over the data frame, as follows:

```
for(i in unique(df$id)){
   indexer = df$id == i

   # here is how I tried to update the dame frame:
   df[indexer,]$tag <- aux[match(df[indexer,]$tag, aux$key),]$value
}
```

The **expected** result was the `df[indexer,]$tag` updated with the respective values from `aux$value`.
The **actual** result was `df$tag` fulfilled with NA's. I've got no errors, but the following warning message:

> In '[<-.factor'('*tmp*', df$id == i, value = c(NA,  :
>     invalid factor level, NA generated

Before, I was using `df$tag <- aux[match(df$tag, aux$key),]$value`, which worked properly, but some duplicated `df$tags` made the `match()` produce the misplaced updates in a number of rows. I also simulate the subsetting and it works fine. Can someone suggest a solution for this update?

UPDATE (how the final dataset should look like?):

```
 > df
      id       tag
       1  "valueAA"
       2  "valueBB"
       3  "valueRR"
       4  "valueFF"
    (...)     (...)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show exactly what your final data frame should look like?

Comment: `df$tag` is a factor, not a character vector. A factor has a defined set of values it can take: `levels(df$tag)`. You are trying to assign values that are not part of that set - thus the values are `NA`. 
I guess you want something like `merge(df, aux, by.x="tag", by.y="key")`.

Comment: When you create your dataframe use, try using data.frame(id, tag,  stringsAsFactors = FALSE).  This will create a character array and not factors, then your code or the match command should work as expected.

Comment: I also tried to use `merge()`, but it didn't worked. it increases the size of the `df` (which is supposed to stay the same). And made some wrong associations (I believe that was because of eventual duplicated values in `df$tag`).  My actual `df$tag` are SHA1 hashes for commits (either with 40 characters or shortened versions with 7 characters) for different systems.

ps: I have created the `df`with a `read.csv()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my data was breaking all the available *built-in* functions providing me a wrong dataset in the end. Then, my solution (at least, a preliminary one) was the following:

1. to process each subset individually;
2. add each data frame to a list;
3. use `rbindlist(a.list, use.names = T)` to get a complete data frame with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Does this produce the output you expect?

```
df$tag <- aux$value[match(df$tag, aux$key)]
```

`merge()` would work too unless you have duplicates in `aux`.

Comment: Indeed, there is duplicates in `aux`. In fact, that's why i decided to it by subsetting, because the subsets are supposed to eliminates the duplicates.